# expressing the power series as an elementary function

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I want to express the power series

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2} (n+1)(n+2) x^n$$
as an elementary function
What I did was to rearrange the expression a little bit, so that

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2} (n+1)(n+2) x^n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^n \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$$

In this way I can perhaps associate the latter to a Taylor series. Also, it seems that the function is expressed in the form $f(x)=(1-x)^p$ but I do not see it very clear, any suggestions?

Comment: Start with the second  derivative of the geometric series

Comment: Integrate twice.